# PySpark - use datetime object with a PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have created a PandasUDF to return the most recent 'count' for each ID. The 'date' column in the spark DF is a string type(YYYY-mm-dd). In the function below I use pd.to_datetime to convert the string to a datetype to get the max(date) for each ID. The function(below) works just fine when applied to a pandas dataframe.  But when I try to use it in spark I get the following error.

AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike " "values")

I've tried to first cast the date column to a DateType(), but the error stays the same.

```
@pandas_udf("id string, count int", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def recent_date(pdf):
    pdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pdf.date)
    latest_data = (pdf[pdf['date'] == max(pdf['date'])]).copy()
    return latest_data[['id', 'count']]
```

I am calling the function using the following call:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(recent_date)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you applying a pandas_udf for this? This can be easily done in native pyspark itself.

Comment: This is just the stripped down version of my issue, the pandas_udf I am using is a lot more complex

Comment: The schema of the dataframe going as input to `pandas_udf` and coming as the output, need to have the same schema.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying the @pandas_udf("id string, count int", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP) needs to include the date column?

Comment: Yes. Please follow this [documentation link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pandas_udf#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) and read up on the `GROUPED_MAP` aggregation

Comment: If that were the issue, the error wouldn't be an AttributeError for datetime.  According the documentation the only the return type of the dataframe needs to be specified.
The returnType should be a StructType describing the schema of the returned pandas.DataFrame. The column labels of the returned pandas.DataFrame must either match the field names in the defined returnType schema if specified as strings, or match the field data types by position if not strings, e.g. integer indices.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053572/cant-apply-a-pandas-udf-in-pyspark) and checking [supported types](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html#supported-sql-types), current pandas_udf does not support `date` type with grouped map UDF (but it's weird that I can use grouped aggregate UDF with `date` type somehow, not sure if it's because it did not encounter any type-checking logic in my situation).

What I did is just casting the `date` type column (in your case: 'date') to `timestamp` type and then it worked for me.

```
df.withColumn('date', unix_timestamp(col('date'), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast("timestamp")) \
    .groupBy('id').apply(recent_date)
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: I ended up changing datetype to string type earlier in the process, and it worked.  Thanks for the answer.